# Add one component multiply times on one page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

How can I place same component on one page multiply times? I have input component who get props and do some stuff. I need to place more than one inputs in one page and i thought i can just copy/paste my component but i get error because vue is thinking that all of my components are the same dom element. how can I put them?

`index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <Input name="name" />
    <Input name="surname" />
    <Input name="pass" />
  </div>
</template>
```

`Input.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="inputs">
    <label class="inputs__label" :for="name">Имя</label>
    <input
      v-click-outside="moveR"
      class="inputs__input"
      :name="name"
      type="text"
      @click="moveL($event.target)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vClickOutside from 'v-click-outside'

export default {
  directives: {
    clickOutside: vClickOutside.directive,
  },
  props: ['name'],
  methods: {
    moveR(e) {
      console.log(e)
      e.classList.add('inputs__lable_r')
    },
    moveL(e) {
      console.log(e)
      e.classList.remove('inputs__lable_r')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

iam sorry i dont have a big baggage of knowledge of vue and google doesnt gave me needed information
i write on nuxt but i think its same trouble with vue

Comment: Could you show exactly what error you received?
And if you want the label to be connected with the "name" variable to the input field, you need to add `:id="name"` to the input field

Comment: Try maybe naming them as `BaseInput.vue` because `input` is an HTML tag by itself so there may be a collision here. At the end, `<BaseInput />` and `<base-input />` are the same, hence why `<Input />` and `<input />` may cause an issue.

Comment: i tried to rename component, my error sounds like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')" at 30 string on Input.vue file. that error brings up 2 times per click on input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it should be

```js
moveR(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('inputs__lable_r')
},
```

You were missing a `e.target`, hence it was not targeting the HTML element but rather the event.